# Resize browser window fill canvas dynamically

Tags: javascript, canvas

When change the window size is not going to fill canvas with the gradient...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
function resizeCanvas() {

            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
              canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            draw();

    }
    resizeCanvas();
```

http://codepen.io/tworog/pen/jVoYrz

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas size is already being updated.

In order to get rid of the gradient you need to change Line 48, so that size of the rectangle matches the canvas.

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript to accomplish this, you can just use css. (I made the canvas blue in the following example to prove it's filling the entire page)

```css
canvas {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

html, body, canvas {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```